# Google closure variable window/event/console/... is undeclared error

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm trying to compile one of my HTML5 project using Google Closure. I'm recieving several errors that I don't know how to solve. In fact, it's the same error but for different variables.

Here the errors messages:

variable window is undeclared
variable event is undeclared
variable console is undeclared
variable Audio is undeclared

These variables are Javascript built-in variables. If I compile this same project directly in command-line, it works. But, in my case, I need to compile this project using an ant file (build process). My ant build script is using the same jar file that I use in command-line. With the option warnings="verbose", it doesn't work. If I remove it, it works. If I would like to use the option warnings-"verbose", what I have to do? Please explain me the difference.

Could somebody help me please?
Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like the default externs are not getting included. Can you post the compiler options/flags you are using?

Comment: What Chad said.  How are you running the compiler?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The option --warnings=verbose sets the compiler to "ninja mode"; i.e. every single variable in your file should be declared (an annotated!) correctly. For example, the **window** variable is unknown to the compiler, but Closure has an implementation of window (independent of the platform used). If your variables are included in some other file, use [externs](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#externs). If yo still want to use Verbose mode without the 'undeclared variable' error, use the flag **--jscomp_off=checkVars**